# Add WMTS (GRB) to Arcgis Silverlight application

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight, wmts, tiling-scheme

I want to simply add the WMTS of the GRB (agiv belgium) to my ArcGIS silverlight application (in xaml). I have found and succesfully tested the sample code on the arcgis developers website, but when I use the GRB WMTS is gives an error "Tiling scheme not supported at this time". Does this have something to do with the CRS?

The GRB WMTS = http://grb.agiv.be/geodiensten/raadpleegdiensten/geocache/wmts?service=WMTS&request=Getcapabilities

```
    <esri:Map WrapAround="True" Name="MyMap"  Margin="0,0,-592,-347">
        <esri:WmtsLayer ServiceMode="KVP" 
              Url="http://grb.agiv.be/geodiensten/raadpleegdiensten/geocache/wmts?"/>
    </esri:Map>
```